# Class methods vs class members?

Tags: c++, header-files, theory

My knowledge of C++ is limited as I've only started using it about 8 months ago. Recently I've received a review comment on my code that states:

"The header doesn't define all class methods before members in the public section"

Sounds simple, or so I thought. Until I realized I don't quite know the theory behind this. What is class method vs members?

Am I right in understanding that `int a` is a class member, while `double doubleToInt(int a)` is a class method?

Comment: Technically both functions and variables are members of the class.  That is why they are called member functions and member variables.

Comment: Member functions are often called *methods*.

Comment: The person commenting seems to come from a Java/C# background IMO. C++ classes have member variables and functions. So in general one would say both are "a class member". However, the comment simply means that variables should come after the functions in the class's definition. It's one way to organize code, and if it's the shop guideline at your place, might as well.

Comment: Also worth noting, your header is likely "declaring" the function (for example `double getVal();`) while your cpp file is probably "defining" the function (`double MyClass::getVal() { return 1.0;}`)

Comment: A note to the note by @RyanP - For such short functions one might as well define them inline

Comment: @StoryTeller Of course, it's a rather bad guideline for C++. More than once, I've had to declare a function like `decltype(someMemberVariable)::const_iterator findSomething() const;`.

Comment: @Angew - I concur. But when it comes to C++ and readability, I think there are battles more worth fighting in code review.

Comment: @StoryTeller Of course. I was just trying to show something that would fit in the comment section to illustrate. If someone is saying that "The header doesn't define all class methods before members in the public section" its worth pointing out that short of inlines or templates the class functions are probably just declarations in the header file, not definitions.